# How to pass List<object> or DataTable to Postgres stored procedure using C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am using C# for CRUD operations and using Postgres as my database. I was using Dapper for my operations. But I am stuck when I want to execute multiple queries. I don't want to make multiple connections to the database. So I thought of using the stored procedures. But I am not able to find a way to pass a `List<object>` or a `DataTable` directly as a parameter in the Postgres stored procedure.

Is there any resource where I can read more about this topic?

What are the standard ways to execute multiple queries on a list/array/datatable with postgres?

For simple insertions, I am using this method right now.

```
try
{
    connection.Execute(
        $@"INSERT INTO amazon.sales (platformproductid, valuationdate, shippedrevenue, shippedunits)
            VALUES ((SELECT Id FROM Test.TableName Where Platformcode = @ASIN and ChannelId = {channelId} and IsActive = true), @valuationDate, @shippedRevenue, @shippedUnits)
            ON CONFLICT (platformproductid, valuationdate) DO UPDATE
            SET shippedrevenue = EXCLUDED.shippedrevenue,
                shippedunits = EXCLUDED.shippedunits;",
        salesData,
        transaction
    );

    transaction.Commit();
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    transaction.Rollback();
    return false;    
}
```

When I am trying to execute this logic. I am facing syntax errors:

```
connection.Execute(
    $@"
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Amazon.ProductMaster WHERE PlatformCode = @ASIN AND ChannelId = @ChannelId AND IsActive = true) THEN
        INSERT INTO Amazon.Inventory (
            ValuationDate,
            PlatformProductId,
            Quantity
        ) VALUES (
            @ValuationDate,
            (SELECT Id FROM Amazon.ProductMaster WHERE PlatformCode = @ASIN AND ChannelId = @ChannelId AND IsActive = true),
            @Quantity
        ) ON CONFLICT (ValuationDate, PlatformProductId) DO UPDATE SET
            Quantity = excluded.Quantity;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO BSC.MissingData (ValuationDate, ProcessId, MissingValue)
        VALUES (
            @ValuationDate,
            (SELECT Id FROM BSC.ProcessList WHERE Name = 'Inventory' AND ChannelId = @ChannelId),
            @ASIN
        );
    END IF;
    ",
     inventoryData,
    transaction
);
```

I am new to Postgres. To simplify these operations, I tried using stored procedures but I am not able to pass my `List<object>` as a parameter. How can I handle this in Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSql you can define a procedure that takes an array of primitive data types as a parameter.
For example,

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION return_array_as_tbl(names text[])
  RETURNS TABLE(name text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT UNNEST(names) AS name;
END
$$;
```

You can also define your own composite type in Postgres,
e.g. `CREATE TYPE public.person AS (name text, age int, has_pets bool);`
and then you can use a array of that type as your procedure parameter
e.g. `CREATE PROCEDURE update_people(people person[])`.

As mentioned in the answer from @DomiGeek, the very popular [Npgsql ADO.Net library](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html) lets you pass in primitive arrays with the [NpgsqlDbType.Array](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) parameter type, accomodating a `List<T>`
or you can add a few lines to support your custom [CompositeType](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html#creating-your-types)

Comment: But will I need to add a for loop to iterate over thousands of rows? @mdisibio

Comment: Not necessarily. There might be a very extreme upper limit to the parameter size for one statement. You can also break it up into batches of a couple hundred arrays if that meets your design requirements. If it is thousands of rows of a very complex type, maybe consider passing it in as a json document as @DomiGeek suggested

However, in general, when binding a collection to a array type parameter with Npgsql, you only need to bind the entire collection to the param as a single value, in a single DbCommand.

Answer (score -1):

To pass a List or DataTable to a PostgreSQL stored procedure, you can use the Npgsql library, which is a .NET data provider for PostgreSQL. The process involves serializing your List or DataTable into a format that PostgreSQL can understand (like JSON) and then passing it to the stored procedure as a parameter.

```
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myList);
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("json_data", json, DbType.String);
    
connection.Execute("your_procedure_name", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: This reads as ai generated

Comment: Its not really.  I speak french and I ask to AI to correct my english only. Its a bad things ?